# Player missing in unity exe

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exe

I want to export my game in .exe format, but for each export, my player disappears, and I don't understand why. I had error messages about missing script at the beginning, but I have nothing now. I tried to change versions of Unity, but nothing works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDoOO.jpg)

Comment: Read the errors in your console.

Comment: Also, where it says "enter image description here" perhaps you should enter a description of your image.